# Filter playlist videos based on date they were added

Tags: jq, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I have been going through YoutubeDL's readme, it's pretty detailed, but I could find a way to filter videos of a playlist based date they were added to the playlist.

I am looking for something very similar to `dateafter` but for the date added, not uploaded.

I thought I could use `match-filter`, but I don't see any relevant keys when I run:

```
youtube-dl --skip-download --print-json <playlist_url> | jq keys
```

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: It seems there only one date, which is uploaded date.

Comment: Date a video was added to the playlist? I don't know if it makes that data available in the extractor. It appears to exist in the [official APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) (`snippet.publishedAt`) however, so you'll either need to put in a request to add or obtain it some other way.

Comment: Please include a sample output from `youtube-dl` in your question, otherwise it will be unanswerable